# Different Color Intenensities from simple ON/OFF RGB subpixels

Tags: optics, visible-light, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I recently got interested in electronic paper.
One design that I liked was the one from Mirasol: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interferometric_modulator_display

[image]

However, what I don't understand, is the following:
**Their subpixels are either ON (color) or OFF (black). 
Therefore, I am wondering how they can produce lighter and darker colors?**

By lighter and darker colors, I mean that the color intensity is tuned. For instance for red:

[image]

Comment: From the article, it looks like the pixels can only be on or off. But that's OK for many types of displays (but not for applications like TV screens). Also, intermediate shades of colors can be visually shown through pixel "dithering" which is how newspapers are able to display the appearance of gray-scale pictures even if they only have black ink.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment. Can you point me to any explanation of dithering for someone who is not from the field ? Thanks.

Comment: Very quick and simple description of dithering: http://webstyleguide.com/wsg2/graphics/dither.html

Comment: Note that one pixel has many sub pixels.

Comment: @JonCuster - I didn't even look closely at the diagram to notice that. Yes, if those individual blocks represent sub pixels, then it looks like there is 14-bit control over the intensity of each of the three primary colors. As pixels go, though, that's pretty big pixel with 6x7=42 sub pixels in it.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand, is the following: Their subpixels are either ON (color) or OFF (black). Therefore, I am wondering how they can produce lighter and darker colors?

It is a front illuminated display, operating on ambient light. When the display is not updated no power is being used, similar to [epaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper).

In the *off* condition a subpixel is black. In the *on* condition a subpixel is fully (100%) reflective for its time interval, it is the frequency of the intervals the determines the intensity and the combination of the subpixels that determines the color of each pixel. (Source: Page: 33, Column 7-Rows 40 through 65 of the following Patent).

The link you provided, in reference 6, leads to the Patent [US5835255A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5835255) "Visible spectrum modulator arrays" which explains the details behind their operation:

> Page: 34 Column 9-Row 20 - "The pulse stream on each line **168** has a duty cycle appropriate to achieve the proper percentages of reflectance  for the three Sections of each tri-dipole. Referring to FIGS. **10**A, **10**B, and **10**C, for example, pulse stream **170** has a period T and a 50% duty cycle. For the first 50% of each period T the input to bias source **164** is high and the corresponding output of source **164** is a high voltage. During this portion of the cycle dipole antenna **80** will reflect all received light having the dipole antenna's resonant wavelength. For the second 50% of the cycle the output of source **164** will be low and dipole antennas **80** will absorb the received light. In FIGS. **10**B, **10**C, pulse streams **172**, **174** represent a 30% duty cycle and a 100% duty cycle respectively; with a 30% duty cycle the effective intensity of the light radiation of the dipole antennas of the section will be 30%; for a duty cycle of 100%, the effective intensity is 100%.
>
> For example, if a particular pixel of the image is to be brown, the relative intensities required of the three red, 25 green, and blue sections 60, 62, 64 may be, respectively, 30, 40, and 10. The input signals to the bias sources **164**, carried on lines **168**, would then have duty cycles, respectively, of 30%, 40%, and 10%. An adjacent pixel which is to be a 
>   brown of the same hue but greater brightness might require duty cycles of 45%, 60%, and 15%.
>
> Referring to FIG. **11**, to accomplish the delivery of the pulse width modulated signals from circuitry **26** to the pixel circuit modules **46**, each circuit module **46** in the row includes storage **180**, **182** for two bits. The bit 1 storage elements **180** of the modules **46** in the row are connected together to create one long shift register with the pulse width modulated signals being passed along the row data line **184** from pixel to pixel. If, for example, the period of the modulated signals is 1 millisecond and there are ten different intensity levels, then an entire string of bits (representing the on or off state of the respective pixels in the row during the succeeding 1/20 millisecond) is shifted down the row every 1/10 millisecond. At the end of the initial 1/10 millisecond all of the bits in elements **180** are shifted to the associated elements **182** by a strobe Pulse on strobe line **186**. The content of each element **182** is the input to the driver **188** for the appropriate one of the three colors of that pixel, which in turn drives the corresponding section 60, 62, 64 of the tri-dipole. The rate at which data is shifted along the shift registers is determined by the number of elements on a given row, the number of rows, the number of intensity levels, and the refresh rate of the entire array.

[image: Figures 10A, B and C.]

[image: Figure 11]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So, to sum it up: They use pulse-width modulation, like for a diode, to obtain different intensities of colors. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, the [duty cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_cycle) determines the intensity.